# Cannot iterate an one to many relation in Grails json-views when relation is defined as list

Tags: json, grails

I have an issue with Grails new json-views and a one-to-many association. The following code is working:

Class Foo:

```
class Foo {

    String name 

    static hasMany = [bars:Bar]

    static constraints = {
    }

}
```

Class Bar:

```
class Bar {

    String name
    Foo foo

    static constraints = {
    }

}
```

Json view for foo (show.gson):

```
model {
    Foo foo
}

json {
    foo g.render(template:"foo", model:[foo:foo])
}
```

_foo.gson template:

```
model {
    Foo foo
}

json {
    name foo.name
    bars foo.bars.collect { it.id }
}
```

But if I change the foo class to use a List instead like this:

```
class Foo {

    String name

    List bars

    static hasMany = [bars:Bar]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

I get the following error :

> [Static type checking] - No such property: id for class: java.lang.Object
>    @ line 13, column 29.
>          bars foo.bars.collect { it.id }

I am sure there are ways around this but I was wondering if anyone has experienced this and know of why it doesn't work when a List is used.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Please file a request at https://github.com/grails/grails-views/issues and we will take a look.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @jeff-scott-brown Thanks! Request created here [link](https://github.com/grails/grails-views/issues/38)

Answer (score 0):

As noted on the issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-views/issues/38, the collection needs to be declared as `List<Bar> bars`, not `List bars`.